# why visual studio remote debugger does not stop at breakpoints, after I rebuild the same code?

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I find it strange, because I rebuild the same code. Theoretically the dll and pdb file should be the same, because the code does not change. Even if it changes, where the breakpoints are located should not be changed.

Comment: Is the solution set to "Debug" in Configuration Manager?

Comment: @DevDev yes. I build two times the same code with `Debug`